# Google Native Client Visual Studio Add-in: Webserver fails to start because arguments to httpd.py are invalid

Tags: c++, visual-studio, google-nativeclient

I have an application that I turned into a simple Native Client App a year ago, and I've been trying to get it running again. However, when I try to run it, or any of the example VS projects, the web server fails to start, giving me usage hints for httpd.py, and saying "httpd.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 5103".

I wasn't able to find anything about this on the NaCL guide or on the net. I could probably troubleshoot the issue if I could see the script that starts the webserver, but I have no idea where this is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script that start the server is 'nacl_sdk\pepper_43\tools\httpd.py'. The problem is with the port argument being formated incorrectly.

The expected format is:

```
httpd.py [-h] [-C SERVE_DIR] [-p PORT] [--no-dir-check]
```

But, the received arguments formatted by the add-in is:

```
['--no_dir_check', '5103']
```

where the port prefix is missing and should be '-p 5103'

For a quick fix, add the following line

```
parser.add_argument('args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
```

before the `parse_args(args)` in the `main(args)` method in httpd.py.

This will keep the unknown arguments from being parsed and will use the default value for port instead (5103).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant I didn't know where the addon script/code that calls httpd.py was. Because my first instinct was to try something like you are suggesting, but I didn't even know what exactly VS was actually saying to httpd.py. Could you tell where to find this code, in case I run in to similar issues in the future? (I assume you know where it is, otherwise I don't know how you would have answered my question.) Anyways, this is very helpful, thank you. I will accept once I confirm it works (I'm at work right now).

Comment: Your fix worked - although I was not able to find the "parse_args(args)" line you mentioned. I simply put the line after the variable "parser" was initialized.